# Trying to turn on/off iis website in c#

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7

I looking for a c# .Net application (web or desktop) that stop/start a IIS website.

I was searching on internet about this and i can't find a example or explanation that works.

I found this dll http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

this is an example that i'm doing to try to stop/start a IIS website:

"using Microsoft.Web.Administration" reference..

```
var server = new ServerManager();
var site = server.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "SITENAME");  
if (site != null)
        {
            //stop the site...
            site.Stop();
            if (site.State == ObjectState.Stopped)
            {
                //do deployment tasks...
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not stop website!");
            }
            //restart the site...
            site.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not find website!");
        }
```

site.Stop throw an exception:

```
"Access denied. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
```

ExceptionType "UnauthorizedAccessException"

How can i do this? what im doing wrong?

Comment: The error seems pretty obvious, the security context your application is running under does not have permission.  If your program itself is running under IIS make sure the app pool it's using has a privileged user account.

Comment: Either you can run the application with "Run as administrator" or do the privilege elevation process programmatically. This seemed to me a good starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756996 .

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on my comment:
The error seems pretty obvious, the security context your application is running under does not have permission. If your program itself is running under IIS make sure the app pool it's using has a privileged user account.

In IIS your website runs under an Application Pool. Make sure that application pool is using an Identity that has adequate permission.  The default ApplicationPoolIdentity account does not have elevated permissions for good reason.

For testing purposes you can use your own login for this since you indicated it had administrative permissions.

[image]

Comment: the only way that works is starting visual studio as administrator.

Comment: Ok, so you are using the Visual Studio web server (aka "Cassini"). I believe this does indeed run in the context of the logged in user so that means if you run Visual Studio as Administrator it would make sense that it works.  When you deploy to IIS use the instructions I provided in this answer.  (Also, if your problem is solved and this answer was helpful please mark it as the answer to your question) Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run the program as an administrator.

Comment: @kingdango's comment is better than this answer.